# How do I add librosa (python lib) to aws lambda using serverless

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm trying to use https://www.serverless.com/ to manage dependencies for a simple aws lambda function.

A key dependency is the librosa python library (https://github.com/librosa/librosa).

I am new to `serverless`, so I'd appreciate guidance with the `serverless.yml` file.

So far I have

```
service: my-app-123
app: my-app-123-app
org: my-org

frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6

stage: dev
region: eu-west-2

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello

package:
  individually: false
  exclude:
    - '**/*'
  include:
    - handler.py
```

and `requirements.txt` is:

```
librosa==0.8.0
pandas==1.1.5
```

When I tried the above I got this error:

```
An error occurred: HelloLambdaFunction - Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: f6bd001e-5592-44c8-8f10-3b56180d7ec7; Proxy: null).
```

Comment: pandas is not that large. I guess librosa takes all that space?

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting the size limitations of your AWS Lambda deployment package, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html). It can be maximal 250 MB unzipped (that's what your error message tells you).

Have a look at the section *Dealing with Lambda's size limitations* in the documentation of the [serverless-python-requirements](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements#dealing-with-lambdas-size-limitations) plugin.

In short what `serverless-python-requirements` recommends/supports is:

- Compress the dependency
- Add a [Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) (e.g. `librosa` alone)

---

Compression works by adding the following in your `serverless.yml`

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    zip: true
```

and then add this to your handler before using your dependencies:

```
try:
  import unzip_requirements
except ImportError:
  pass
```

---

But some users seem to have had issues with `librosa` and couldn't seem to make it work, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/406) for example or this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698606/aws-lambda-audio-features-extraction-not-enough-storage-layers).

A suggestion in there was to split up your Lambdas and chain them, i.e. one Lambda which has only `librosa` as a dependency (maybe with compression of the dependency) and then handing off for further processing to a second Lambda, I don't know what you're trying to do if this is feasible for you.

Comment: Thank you. I tested a few ways to get `librosa` alone into a lambda and the only one that worked was to run from a container image in ECR. I think I'll do that.